# Python equivalent to replace() in R

Tags: python, replace, conditional-statements

Is there a powerful replace function in Python, something equivalent to replace(x, l, y) in R?
e.g.

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0]
l = [True,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True, False]
y = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The number of values in y matches the number of True in l.  In R,
replace(x, l, y) will have x replaced by y corresponding to the True positions in l.

Is there a similar function in Python I can call?  If not, any suggestions how to make it working?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: There's no such function as far as I know. But you can develop one for sure.

Comment: `numpy` can do that, even more naturally:  `x[l]=y`.  Most array-based functions are available in `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks much, Tim and Daniel.  Wish you a wonderful weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of `True`s and the number of elements in `y` are the same, we can a generator over `y`, and then use a list comprehension to build the result. We extract from `y` if the corresponding element in `l` is `True`, else we extract from `x`:

```py
iter_y = iter(y)

[next(iter_y) if l_item else x_item for l_item, x_item in zip(l, x)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]
```